# After updating to Fedora 27, Files application looks horrible. Details in the description below

Tags: fedora, nautilus

I have just updated my system to Fedora 27 from Fedora 26. After updating I noticed that the Files application is not showing the folders or files properly. Here is a screenshot,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJibe.jpg
This was not happening in Fedora 26.
Does any one know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pango package issue. See here-
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?316160-Issue-with-viewing-icons-in-thunar

Bug has been filed.